# Issue with Sphinx Attributes

Tags: mysql, sphinx

Lets say I have an **adverts** table, which I'm trying to filter on. Each advert can have many "types" which are stored in the **types** table, associated to with an **advert_types** table in the middle. Pretty standard:

```
adverts
-------
id
name

types
-----
id
name

advert_types
------------
id
advert_id
type_id
```

I'm simply trying to search for all adverts that are IN one or more type IDs as chosen by the user:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, at.type_id
    FROM adverts as a
    LEFT JOIN advert_types as at 
    ON a.id = at.advert_id
    WHERE at.type_id IN(1,2);
```

I should note here that an advert does not NEED to have a type associated with it (hence the left join).

Lets say type ID 1 is named "books" and type ID 2 is named "magazines". In the above query I'd expect to receive all adverts that are for books, for magazines, or for both books AND magazines.

This works fine in MySQL, but not so well in my Sphinx index, which is my problem. If I filter on "magazines", I only get adverts with magazines returned; none with both books and magazines. However, if I search for "books" I successfully get everything as I want. I can't see where I'm going wrong. Do I need a different type of join in my index? Or maybe a different sort mode in Sphinx.

I've successfully done the same in a different filter, but on a 1:1 relationship, so something leads me to believe I have a problem in my query and the way Sphinx handles multiple records.

Comment: please include your 'source' section from sphinx.conf, at the moment you havent specified how you actully indexing the table (dont forget to remove your database access details from what you include!)